# Assign height and width of dynamically created image to canvas using c#

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to assign height and width of dynamically created image to a canvas .
Here is my code

```
Image image=new Image();
BitmapImage bm=new BitmapImage();
bm.UriSource=new Uri("url",Urikind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
image.Source=bm;
MyCanvas.Height=image.Height;
MyCanvas.Width=image.Width;
```

but it gives 0.0 value when i check in debug mode ,when I change image.Height to image.ActualHeight it gives NaN .
How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of the `Image` control. The `Width` and `Height` are the dimensions you *want* the control to have; by default their value is `double.NaN`, which means "Auto".

But anyway, it still won't be enough:

- at this point, the image has not finished loading, so its width and height are not accessible yet. You need to initialize the image like that:

  BitmapImage bm=new BitmapImage();
  bm.BeginInit();
  bm.UriSource=new Uri("url",Urikind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
  bm.EndInit();
- the `Image` control is not yet part of the visual tree, so its dimensions can't be computed

So `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` will still not give your the correct values... A better way would be to set the canvas size according to the width and height of the `BitmapImage`:

```
MyCanvas.Height= bm.Height;
MyCanvas.Width = bm.Width;
```

Comment: @user3355043, sorry, I didn't realize it was a WinRT application... My answer applies to WPF, not WinRT. Forget about the BeginInit/EndInit methods, they don't exist in WinRT. Try to use the PixelWidth and PixelHeight instead

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way

```
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
 bm.UriSource=new Uri("ms-appx:///" + d.source, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 bm.ImageOpened += (sender, e1) =>
  {
   DrawCanvas.Height = bm.PixelHeight;
   DrawCanvas.Width = bm.PixelWidth;
   };
```